# Set custom argv[0] for shell script

Tags: shell, process, argv

If you have a script that starts with a shebang like this

```
#!/bin/sh

echo argv0 is $0
```

or this

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
print(f"argv0 is {sys.argv[0]}")
```

and you run it with a custom `argv[0]`, e.g. like this (in Python)

```py
subprocess.run(["fake_argv0"], executable="./real_script")
```

then for some reason it will actually print this:

```
argv0 is ./real_script
```

Why does this happen and is there any way to work around it, either by changing the way the script is run (the `subprocess.run()` call) or by changing the `#!` line in the script itself?

Comment: It's `executable` that changes the value of `argv0`, not the command list. Your second  Python command is equivalent to `subprocess.run(["./real_script", "fake_argv0"])`.

Comment: POSIX shell does not, that I am aware of, provide a way to specify an alternate value for `$0`. In `bash`, you can use the `-a` argument to `exec` to specify a different name. I'm not aware, either, of a way with `subprocess` to alter the value for the program being executed.

Comment: No it isn't. The first argument is the `argv` to pass to the subprocess. `executable` specifies the actual command to run, it just defaults to `argv[0]`.

Comment: `subprocess.run()` *does* change `argv[0]` successfully. I tested it with a C program. But for some reason if the target is a `#!` script rather than an ELF executable then it goes wrong.

Comment: It's not possible to override `argv[0]` for a shell script because this data gets lost in the process of invoking the interpreter.

Comment: `is there any way to work around it` Around what exactly? Passing arguments?

Comment: @KamilCuk Around the fact that the `argv[0]` I specified is lost.

Comment: @thatotherguy Hmm yeah it certainly seems that way. But it's hard to know for sure without knowing the details. Do you know any?

Comment: @KamilCuk No, there is no `argv[1]`. Try it if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Timmmm [POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) that when running `/bin/sh command_file`, "Special parameter 0 (see Special Parameters) shall be set to the value of command_file"

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you execute a script called `myscript`:

```
#!/bin/foo a b
```

And execute it like this

```
./myscript c d
```

I think what will happen is that the kernel will:

1. Replace `argv[0]` with the name of the script you are executing.
2. Prepend the `#!` contents to `argv`.

So you end up with.

```
/bin/foo a b ./myscript c d
```

Even if you run it with a custom `argv[0]` it the kernel will just replace it. The code to do that is in the Linux kernel [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/886d7de631da71e30909980fdbf318f7caade262/fs/binfmt_script.c#L96-L127).

```c
    /*
     * OK, we've parsed out the interpreter name and
     * (optional) argument.
     * Splice in (1) the interpreter's name for argv[0]
     *           (2) (optional) argument to interpreter
     *           (3) filename of shell script (replace argv[0])
     *
     * This is done in reverse order, because of how the
     * user environment and arguments are stored.
     */
```

For Python it means it ends up executing

```
/usr/bin/python3 ./myscript.py
```

And Python has [some code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/194a9526d8ee6abbbe58ef48520ec87a7e83f327/Lib/runpy.py#L300) to simply delete `argv[0]` so `argv[0]` ends up being `./myscript.py`.